# share wrordpress data between two shared hosts using REST API

Tags: themes, javascript, html, rest-api

I have two shared hosting plans on two different providers. on one I run a wordpress instance and I wanna use vue to get the data from the API to display them on the secon domain on a single page app REST powered website. My question is, can I hide the public access on the wordpress installation and let the api continue working to pass data to the second host?

Comment: Yes, you can hide the public access on the WordPress installation.

Comment: Can you indicate me a way? I'm thinking to use an htaccess on the main wp installation and redirect the users to the other host or delete the htaccess inside wordpress, modify it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ldp-plugin could provide and answer to your requirement to share the content between two hosts
[enter link description here](https://lv.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ldp/)

Regards

Amaury